# Unable to verify commits with gpg - Bitcoin alerts for Nostr

Tags: git, build, git-commit, bitcoind, gpg-signature

I'm trying to run this project on my nostr account https://github.com/yukibtc/bitcoin-alerts with my Windows machine.

As I clone the repo and run the command

```
gpg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys $(<contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys)
```

to import gpg keys, I receive this errors:

gpg: Warning: Enabling DEP failed: Access denied. (0,1)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure.

I followed [these](https://github.com/yukibtc/bitcoin-alerts/blob/master/doc/build.md) instructions and installed https://www.gpg4win.org/get-gpg4win.html on my machine but it seems like there's something not working for me and I need some help as I never worked with encrypted files.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Key that save in github is your public key and you cant use it for encrypt and it's just for decrypt. you need recover your secret key if you can't must generate new key and add it to your github acount

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I followed your suggestion and generated a new key that I linked to my gitHub account. 

Now the problem is that gpg fails at receiving the key. It gives me this error now:

 `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Try again later`

Comment: Are you add your key to your git config?

Answer (score 0):

Key that save in github is your public key and you cant use it for encrypt and it's just for decrypt. you need recover your secret key if you can't must generate new key and add it to your github acount

First generate your key

(I assume you know how to do this, otherwise leave a comment so I can update the answer)

Next list your keys by this code and copy your Key id :

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
```

Key id is highlight in image

[image: gpg Key id]

Now add it to your git config by this code

```
git config user.signingkey YourKeyId
```

Final step is add gpg address to your git

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
```

**EndNote :** for github know your key you must add your public key to your github account if you don't know how do it or any question leave comment for me

I will be happy to help you

**Update :**

**Note :** You must use bottom code in your project folder cmd or your IDE PowerShell to save configuration in your git config file of repository

```
git config user.signingkey YourKeyId
```

For verify commit use this code:

```
git commit -S -m 'Your Message'
```

and some time we need verify `merge` branch by this code

```
git merge -S Branchname
```

push your verified commits to your repository

if is your first time and fear to have the mistake. you can create test repository on git and Practice with it

Comment: Still doesn't work.

With my keys generated I listed my keys with the command:

`gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`

and the output was like the screenshot you attached.

Then I run:

`git config user.signingkey -MyKeyID`

with no output from th console this time. The I run:

`git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"`

always without output. Then I run

`gpg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys $(<contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys)`

and get this output from console:

`gpg: keyserver receive failed: Try again later`

Comment: And if I run `gpg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys $(<contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys)` (the file where I pasted the ID you highlighted) the output is: `" not a key ID: skippingmySupposedKeyID
" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Try again later`.